# How to configure nlog to use IHostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath in FileTarget

Tags: asp.net-core, nlog

I am trying to add NLog for my asp.net core application. So I configured it exactly as described here https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging . Also I added https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web with default configuration too. So far so good, everything working as expected.

Now I want to store my log files not in harcoded folder specified in example `c:\temp\nlog-own-${shortdate}.log` but in folder which depends on current project. In my previous ASP.NET project I used something like this `${basedir}\App_Data\Logs\nlog-own-${shortdate}.log`. Now It is also worked but placed files in bin directory. But I want to configure to place those files in `IHostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath` folder. Basically I want something like this

```cs
    private static Logger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    private IHostingEnvironment _HostingEnvironment;
    public UserController(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _HostingEnvironment = env;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var fileTarget = Logger.Factory.Configuration.FindTargetByName<NLog.Targets.FileTarget>("ownFile-web");
        fileTarget.FileName = new SimpleLayout(
            @"${basedir}\App_Data\Logs\nlog-own-${shortdate}.log"
                .Replace("${basedir}", _HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath)
        );
        Logger.Info("Index page says hello");

        return View(new UserListArgs());
    }
```

but in more elegant way.

Comment: new SimpleLayout(_HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath + 
            @"\App_Data\Logs\nlog-own-${shortdate}.log") ?

Comment: It is same. I do not like that part of NLog configured in nlog.config, and part in code. In ideal I want to set up `${basedir}\App_Data\Logs\nlog-own-${shortdate}.log` in my nlog.config and then in Startup write something like `loggerFactory.AddNLog(new Option {BaseDir = _HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath });` Or maybe I can add new variable for nlog in Startup class, something like `${my-custom-configured-dir}`.

Comment: It's better to use Path.Combine to concat file path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

**Update**: in NLog 4.4 this is possible in one line (`LayoutRenderer.Register`)

**Since NLog 4.4**

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, 
                      ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{

    //add NLog to ASP.NET Core
    loggerFactory.AddNLog(); 

    //needed for non-NETSTANDARD platforms: configure nlog.config in your project root
    env.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config");

    LayoutRenderer.Register("basedir", (logEvent) => env.ContentRootPath);

    ...
 }
```

**Before NLog 4.4**

```cs
[LayoutRenderer("basedir")]
public class AspNetCoreBaseDirLayoutRenderer : LayoutRenderer
{
    public static IHostingEnvironment Env {get;set;}

    protected override void Append(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        builder.Append(env.ContentRootPath);
    }
}
```

Register:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
  {
      //add NLog to ASP.NET Core
      loggerFactory.AddNLog();


      //needed for non-NETSTANDARD platforms: configure nlog.config in your project root
      env.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config");
      ...

      //overwrite ${basedir}
      AspNetCoreBaseDirLayoutRenderer.Env = env;
      ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.LayoutRenderers
          .RegisterDefinition("basedir", typeof(AspNetCoreBaseDirLayoutRenderer ));
      ...
```

Comment: `LayoutRenderer.Register("basedir", (logEvent) => env.ContentRootPath)` solution works for file targets (only when i wrote this line before `env.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config");`). Thank you for this. But it does not work for `internalLogFile` property. It creates empty `${basedir}` folder in env.ContentRootPath folder. Any solution for it?

Comment: the `internalLogFile` property isn't template to keep things simple. You have to set the `internalLogFile` from C#: `InternalLogger.LogFile = ..`. See http://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.4.0/html/P_NLog_Common_InternalLogger_LogFile.htm

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to setup configuration like this :

```cs
    // Step 1. Create configuration object 
    var config = new LoggingConfiguration();

    // Step 2. Create targets and add them to the configuration 
    var consoleTarget = new ColoredConsoleTarget();
    config.AddTarget("console", consoleTarget);

    var fileTarget = new FileTarget();
    config.AddTarget("file", fileTarget);

    // Step 3. Set target properties 
    consoleTarget.Layout = @"${date:format=HH\:mm\:ss} ${logger} ${message}";
    fileTarget.FileName = "${basedir}/file.txt";
    fileTarget.Layout = "${message}";

    // Step 4. Define rules
    var rule1 = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Debug, consoleTarget);
    config.LoggingRules.Add(rule1);

    var rule2 = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Debug, fileTarget);
    config.LoggingRules.Add(rule2);

    // Step 5. Activate the configuration
    LogManager.Configuration = config;
```

Try to override nlog configuration inside your setup.cs.

Comment: Yes, I can do this, so I did in my question example. But I do not wont to override my settings, I want to override/extend nlog settings. So it would be better for me to override `${basedir}` layout renderer or add my own renderer.

Comment: I suppose you want just to generate your log file into parent folder of wwwroot. if you don't edit the contentRootPath,  Why don't you use : "${basedir}/../logs/logFile.log".

Comment: Because `${basedir}` placed files into `WebFolder\bin\Debug\net452\win7-x64` for debug. And I'm afraid that it may be different depends on publish options, so i do not want to write something like this `${basedir}/../../../../logs/‌​logFile.log`

Comment: Publish your web app, you'll see that Dlls and folders will be at the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

[${aspnet-appbasepath}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNet-AppBasePath-layout-renderer) was introduced with NLog.Web.AspNetCore v4.5.0 and NLog.Web v4.5.2

And can be used directly in `NLog.config`:

```xml
<nlog>
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
  </extensions>
  <targets>
     <target type="file" name="ownFile-web" filename="${aspnet-appbasepath}/app-${shortdate}.log" />
  <targets>
  <rules>
     <logger name="*" writeTo="ownFile-web" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```